# input value as event handler function argument is empty string in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, input

I'm working on a javascript Tic-Tac-Toe game. To add players to a game, each player has to enter their name in an input field and select an entity character to use in the grid, which fires an event to add both the name and the character in an array to be pushed onto an array named "players". Here's the parts of the JavaScript program you need to answer my question (the html body is empty and, if possible, I don't want to write any code inside it) :

```
    const body = document.body;
    const id = id => document.getElementById(id);
    const createEl = el => document.createElement(el);
    const players = [];

    const addPlayer = (character, playerName, event) => {
        if (divs.length !== 0) {
            players.push([character, playerName]);
            menu.removeChild(event.target);
            input.value = '';
        } else init2();
    };

    const init1 = () => {
        const label = createEl('label');
        label.setAttribute('for', 'player-name');
        label.textContent = 'Enter player\'s name: ';
        const input = createEl('input');
        input.type = 'text';
        input.id = 'player-name';
        menu.append(label, input);

        const chars = [
            '\u0058', 
            '\u004F',
            '\u0023'
        ];

        for (const char of chars) {
            const div = createEl('div');
            div.textContent = char;
            div.classList.add('char-div');
            div.addEventListener('click', addPlayer.bind(this, char, input.value));
            menu.append(div);
        }
        
        const btn = createEl('button');
        btn.textContent = 'No more players to add';
        btn.addEventListener('click', init2);
        menu.append(btn);
    };
            
    const init = () => {
        const menu = createEl('div');
        menu.id = 'menu';
        body.append(menu);
    };

    init();
    const menu = id('menu');
    init1();
    const input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    const divs = document.getElementsByClassName('char-div');
```

When I enter my name and select a character, the character is successfully pushed to the inner array but not the player's name. The addPlayer function's second argument is always an empty string. I want it to be the player's name (the input field's value).

Comment: What is init2() in you code?

Comment: Instead of making addPlayer be the event listener, make a small anonymous function that calls addPlayer the way you want. `div.addEventListener('click', () => addPlayer(char, input.value));`

Comment: init2() is another menu screen for the game I don't need help for right now. This is only a part of the complete JavaScript program. Thanks for caring, Ermi.